# Is there a way to stop the Calendar control going into Month view?

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I need to add in a Calendar control that will let the user select which month of data they would like to view/export. But when I select a month in the Calendar control it automatically changes the Display Mode to the 'Month' view.

[CalendarDisplayModeChange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WopZk.png)

I am new to C# and WPF so I feel like this should be a straight forward thing. I just don't know the proper syntax. That being said I have tried to turn off manipulation and I tried having the calendar view go back to a 'Year' view if it detects a Display Mode change.

Here is my current XAML code that builds the Calendar.

```
<Calendar Name="MonthCal" DisplayMode="Year" SelectionMode="MultipleRange"/>
```

I would expect the control to A) stay in the 'Year' view and B) provide the selected month information to my program. I could filter the month from the date but that just defeats the purpose of having the user select a month. I would be perfectly happy with a simple message box that said "User Selected X Month". I could take it from there as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitor the event for DisplayModeChanged on the calendar item.

```
   private void MonthCal_DisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (!e.NewMode.Equals(CalendarMode.Year)) { MonthCal.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year; }
    }
```

Comment: No idea what here is different from what I had previously but this worked wonderfully!